# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

estoy comenzando a crear un ecommerce siguiendo un video, pero la versión de la librería que usa el video cambió bastante y estoy teniendo varios errores. Uno es:
Product.js:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

Les dejo el código para ver si alguno puede ayudarme a entender por qué tengo este error.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import CardContent from '@mui/material/CardContent';
import CardActions from '@mui/material/CardActions';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';

import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import { red } from '@mui/material/colors';
import FavoriteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Favorite';
import ShareIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Share';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';
import MoreVertIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreVert';

import { useStateValue } from '../statePRovider';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { ActionTypes } from '@mui/base';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root:{
        maxwidth: 345,
    },
    action: {
        marginTop: "1rem",
    },
    media:{
        height: 0,
        paddingTop: "56.25%",
    },
    expand: {
        transform: "rotate(0deg)",
        marginLeft: "auto",
        transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
        }),
    },
    expandOpen:{
        transform: "rotate(180deg",
    },
}));


const ExpandMore = styled((props) => {
  const { expand, ...other } = props;
  return <IconButton {...other} />;
})(({ theme, expand }) => ({
  transform: !expand ? 'rotate(0deg)' : 'rotate(180deg)',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
  transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
  }),
}));

export default function Product({
    
    product: { id, name, productType, image, price, rating, description },
     
}) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
 const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
    const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  const addToBasket = () => {
      dispatch({
          type: ActionTypes.ADD_TO_BASKET,
          item: {
              id, 
              name,
              productType,
              image,
              price,
              rating,
              description,
          },
      });
    };

  return (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardHeader
     
        action={
          <Typography
            className={classes.action}
            variant='h5'
            color='textSecondary'
            >
                {5}
                </Typography>
        }
        title="Recorriendo Sudamérica"
        subheader="Nicolás Bonder"
      />
      <CardMedia
        className={classes.media}
        component="img"
        height="194"
        image="/static/images/cards/paella.jpg"
        alt="Paella dish"
      />
```

Abajo de eso hay más código pero creo que es irrelevante, ya que el problema está en la linea product: { id, name, productType, image, price, rating, description },

Busqué un par de soluciones, pero no entendí muy bien cómo lo resolvían y los casos eran bastante diferentes a lo que tengo yo.

Comment: Parece un problema en la destructuración del componente Products, `function Product({product: { id, name, productType, image, price, rating, description }})`, intenta asi : `function Product({ id, name, productType, image, price, rating, description })`

Comment: Ok, voy a probar. Gracias.